# How to use Python Regex to match url

Tags: python-3.x, python-regex

I have a string:

test_string="lots of other html tags ,'https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image/2022/202209_166293.png',and still 'https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image/2022/202209_166293.jpg'"

How can I get the whole 2 urls in the string,by using python Regex ?

I tried:

```
pattern = 'https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image'
result = re.findall(pattern, test_string)
```

I can get a list:

```
['https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image','https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image']
```

but not the whole url ,so I tried:

```
pattern = 'https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image...$png'
result = re.findall(pattern, test_string)
```

But received an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match a minimal number of characters after `image` up to a `.` and either `png` or `jpg`:

```
test_string = "lots of other html tags ,'https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image/2022/202209_166293.png',and still 'https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image/2022/202209_166293.jpg'"
pattern = r'https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image.*?\.(?:png|jpg)'
re.findall(pattern, test_string)
```

Output:

```
[
 'https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image/2022/202209_166293.png',
 'https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image/2022/202209_166293.jpg'
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you would always expect the URLs to appear inside single quotes, we can use `re.findall` as follows:

I have a string:

```
test_string = "lots of other html tags ,'https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image/2022/202209_166293.png',and still 'https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image/2022/202209_166293.jpg'"
urls = re.findall(r"'(https?:\S+?)'", test_string)
print(urls)
```

This prints:

```
['https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image/2022/202209_166293.png',
 'https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image/2022/202209_166293.jpg']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match any URL inside the string you have by using the following regex `'(https?://\S+)'`

by applying this to your code it would be something like this:

```py
import re

string = "Some string here'https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image/2022/202209_166293.png' And here as well 'https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image/2022/202209_166293.jpg' that's it tho"

res = re.findall(r"(http(s)?://\S+)", string)

print(res)
```

this will return a list of URLs got collected from the string:

```
[
    'https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image/2022/202209_166293.png', 
    'https://news.sky.net/upload_files/image/2022/202209_166293.jpg'
]
```

###### Regex Explaination:

`'(https?://\S+)'`

- `https?` - to check if the url is `https` or `http`
- `\S+` - any non-whitespace character one or more times

So this will get either `https` or `http` then after `://` characters it will take any non-whitespace character one or more times

Hope you find this helpful.